# how to position these divs in one line, horizontally, with horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, html

I have a container div with a `max-width` and a `max-height`. Inside the container div, there are lots of small divs that i need to scroll through horizontally.

I've hidden the `y-overflow` CSS and used the `inline/inline-block` and have had no luck.

Here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/BRmCk/

I need the other small divs to show up in the parent div, in one line, horizontally.

any ideas?

Comment: Remember that `width: auto; min-width: 200px; max-width: 200px;` is the same like `width: 200px;`

Comment: Just inner wrap the scrolling div with another div which width is set to 1000px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `float: left;` to your `.date_pick_day_cont` class.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BRmCk/6/

Comment: @Nav: see my updated example. You had limited the widths of the containing DIVs. I removed those limits.

Comment: But i need the container div to stay at a fixed width. Thats why i mentioned an x-overflow scroll bar. In your update, the divs do stay in one line, but when there is not enough space left, they move onto a second line, instead of a horizontal scroll bar appearing. Thanks